# Return Valid Enumeration List in ASP.NET Web API Error Response

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

When an API user sends a POST request that includes an invalid enumeration, is there a good way to provide a more helpful error response that includes the valid enumerations?

So if I have a sample Class with an Enumerator:

```
Public Class MyObject
    Public Property MyProp As MyEnum
    Public Enum MyEnum
        Foo
        Bar
    End Enum
End Class
```

And an Action Filter:

```
Public Class ValidateModelAttribute
    Inherits ActionFilterAttribute
    Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(actionContext As HttpActionContext)
        If actionContext.ModelState.IsValid = False Then
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

If the user sends something like:

```
{
    "MyProp": "NotValid"
}
```

The action filter sends an error response like:

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "value.MyProp.MyEnum": [
      "Error converting value \"NotValid\" to type 'API.MyObject+MyEnum'. Path 'MyObject.MyEnum', line 29, position 32."
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to send a more useful error response, such as:

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "value.MyProp.MyEnum": [
      "'NotValid' is not a valid value for MyProp; Valid values include 'Foo','Bar'"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any thoughts on how I could handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom converter to deserialize enumerations. The converter throws an error if it's unable to parse the JsonReader's value into the target enum.

```
Public Class EnumConverter
    Inherits JsonConverter
    Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
        Try
            'if the enum parses properly, deserialize the object like usual
            Dim tryParse As Object = [Enum].Parse(objectType, reader.Value)
            Return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'value wasn't valid - return a response stating such and indicating the valid values
            Dim valid As String = String.Format("'{0}'", String.Join(",", [Enum].GetNames(objectType)).Replace(",", "','"))
            Throw New FormatException(String.Format("'{0}' is not a valid value for {1}; Valid values include: {2}", reader.Value, reader.Path, valid))
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
    Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
        'use the default serialization
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

...

```
Public Class MyObject
    <JsonConverter(GetType(EnumConverter))> _
    Public Property MyProp As MyEnum
    Public Enum MyEnum
        Foo
        Bar
    End Enum
End Class
```